# imacros : error GetRandomint should be easy for answering

Tags: imacros

ReferenceError: getRandomInt is not defined, line 12 (Error code: -991) i get this error when i run this script

```
var macro;
macro ="CODE:";
macro +="VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX"+"\n";
macro +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
macro +="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO={{link}}"+"\n";


var link=["www.google.com","www.youtube.com","www.yahoo.com"];

var random=getRandomInt(1,3);

random--;

iimSet("link",link[random])
iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: Maybe because you're calling a method that you haven't made?

Comment: yes i think that is the problem i have very little knowledge in javascript so can you maybe fix that line?

Comment: You want to get a random integer between 1 and 3?

Comment: i want the script to go to the links randomly each time it plays (only one link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array index start with 0, you need a number between 0 and 2

```
var random = Math.random() * 2;
iimSet("link",link[random])
iimPlay(macro)
```

OR

```
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
iimSet("link",link[random])
iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: can you check this out mate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904881/imacros-javascript-i-get-www-undefined-com-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// ...
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*link.length)
iimSet("link",link[random])
iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: can you check this out mate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904881/imacros-javascript-i-get-www-undefined-com-error