# imacros: javascript i get www._undefined_.com error

Tags: imacros

so when i run this macro in imacros it directs me to www.*undefined*.com
any ideas how i can fix this?

also: it directs me to the first url but when it loops the second time it gets to that site

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX"+"\n";
macro +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
macro +="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO={{random}}"+"\n";

var am = "www.google.com"
var amc = "www.youtube.com"
var amb = "www.yahoo.com"


var link=[am, amc, amb];

#this is for selecting a random value

var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
iimSet("link",link[random])
iimPlay(macro)

#this is for looping 10 times

var n=10;




for(var i=0;i<n;i++)

{

iimPlay(macro)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again. Just apply this:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*link.length);
```

And according to your iim-code, set 'random' instead of 'link' :

```
iimSet("random",link[random]);
```